# hidesbarsonswipe mutates view size

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationcontroller

I am having trouble with this piece of code:

```
navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
```

My navigation controller's root view controller is a UICollectionViewController.  The blue view below is a cell that represents the user's current screen.  I think the problem is that I need to resize the cell when the navigation bar hides.

I set the cell size like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height - 44)
}
```

I am not breaking any constraints, and I am very sure everything is set up properly.  But when I swipe up, this happens:

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

As you can see, the view gets shortened.  I can't find those measurements anywhere in my code.

Is there a way to ensure that the view gets resized properly?

Comment: The view isn't getting shortened. It's moving up to fill the hole left when the navigation bar goes away. Do you know how to change the size of a view? Show your code, please if you need additional help. But maybe that's enough to get you on track...

Comment: Are you saying that I need to resize the view manually?  It seems like the app should take care of that on its own.

Comment: @Mozahler I think the problem is that I am using a collection view controller where each cell acts as a view for the entire screen.  The navigation controller detects the scroll, but doesn't change the size of the cell.  Is there a way to track this hiding of the navigation bar so that I can change the size of the cell?

Comment: It can if you've configured it that way. You absolutely can fix that in IB. I normally do it programmatically in viewDidLoad  I've given you enough information to fix it. If you can't figure it out I can show you how. But not this morning. I'll check in this afternoon to see how you've made out.

Comment: @Mozahler Yeah my project doesn't use IB.  If I add my above comment about the structure, include some code, can you provide this programmatic method in an answer?

Comment: Sure. A bit later today. I'm running late for an appointment. Maybe someone else will jump in before I get back.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your viewDidLoad() and you should be good to go.

```
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
    yourBlueView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(yourBlueView)
    yourBlueView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    yourBlueView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    yourBlueView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    yourBlueView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Edit:
Change yourBlueView to the name you've given that particular UIView.  Let me know if you get stuck, but do try to figure it out first. That's the best way to learn it and retain it.

The bar on the bottom takes at least 44 and I notice it's going under the nav bar at the top. Remove your hard code sizing which is too high,  and only use the auto layout

Second Edit: (This is a non-autolayout approach)

```
let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"
```

This code goes in viewDidLoad:

```
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
let displaySize =  UIScreen.main.bounds
let displayHeight = displaySize.height - 40
let displayWidth = displaySize.width

layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: displayWidth, height: displayHeight)
if let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout) {
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self

    collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.view.addSubview(collectionView!)
}
```

Comment: Okay, I am stuck.  I really did try.  I tried this for the leading anchor: `collectionView?.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (navigationController?.topViewController?.view.leadingAnchor)!).isActive = true`

Comment: I confirmed that the navigation controller had a top view controller.  Also, the above comment can't be correct because I am referencing the same view twice.  I just realized this

Comment: that code works, but the cells' heights remain unchanged.

Comment: Yes you added key information after I wrote that code. I'll take a look at the information you added when I get home. Please show how you set the cell size and this won't be difficult.

Comment: sorry, added that info

Comment: Your attempt above was close. leading and trailing are left and right (width). You're interested in topAnchor and BottomAnchor (height). Also, you're constraining the collectionView, not the individual cells.

Comment: Right, but don't I have to set the cell's bounds?  Would I have to change those bounds if I do it this way?  I should really just use a tab bar, I can't remember why I did it this way.

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I show you how I create a full-screen cell that swipes horizontally. It doesn't use auto layout.  The one difference in my example is that I don't have a tab bar at the bottom. I'll edit my answer.